# AWS Node.js Lambda HTTPS Request Not Sending Data To Facebook Conversions API

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, aws-lambda, https, facebook-conversions-api

I am attempting to send data to Facebook Conversion API via an AWS Lambda function written in node.js. [Documentation here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/using-the-api).

All data is passed successfully to the function via API gateway and external `GET` requests.

However when the function executes, there's no indication the data was actually sent, as there is no response logged from Facebook.

The current code is as follows:

```
const https = require('https');

let path = '/v15.0/' + pixelId +'/events?access_token='+ access_token;
            var options = {
                'method': 'POST',
                'hostname': 'graph.facebook.com',
                'path': path
              ,
              'headers': {
                'port': '443',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              }};
            
              var body = [{
                "data": [
                    {
                        "event_name": conversionEvent,
                        "event_time": current_timestamp,
                        "action_source": "website",
                        "event_source_url": site,
                        "event_id": current_timestamp * Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
                        "user_data": {
                            "em": email,
                            "phone": phone,
                            "fn": fName,
                            "ln": lName,
                            "client_ip_address": userIp,
                            "st": userState,
                            "zp": userZip,
                            "ct": userCity,
                            "fbc": clickId
                        }
                    }
                ]
                }];

                console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
                
                var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
                    var chunks = [];
                  
                    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
                        chunks.push(chunk);
                    });
                  
                    res.on("end", function (chunk) {
                     var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
                     console.log(body.toString());
                     console.log("END");
                      response.statusCode = 200;
                      response.body = JSON.stringify("Success");
                    });
                  
                    res.on("error", function (error) {
                      console.error(error);
                      response.body = JSON.stringify("Error Posting Data to Facebook " + JSON.stringify(error));
                    })
                  });

                  req.write(JSON.stringify(body));
        
                  req.end();
```

I've also modified the lambda function to timeout at 30 seconds, rather than 3. Also note the function is NOT operating within a private VPC.

Here's a screenshot of the log output:
[image]

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const https = require('https');

exports.handler = async (event) =&gt; {

    let path = '/v15.0/' + pixelId +'/events?access_token='+ access_token;
                var options = {
                    'method': 'POST',
                    'hostname': 'graph.facebook.com',
                    'path': path
                  ,
                  'headers': {
                    'port': '443',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                  }};
                
                  var body = [{
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "event_name": conversionEvent,
                            "event_time": current_timestamp,
                            "action_source": "website",
                            "event_source_url": site,
                            "event_id": current_timestamp * Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
                            "user_data": {
                                "em": email,
                                "phone": phone,
                                "fn": fName,
                                "ln": l
```